# Open a new VC when pressing a button from a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

The problem is when I m trying to open a new VC when a button from a specific tableViewCell is pressed. 
 Bellow is my tableView which is loading the cells. The one from section 0 is the one with the button.

```
class NewConversationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else if section == 1{
        return friendList.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewGroupConversationCell") as! NewGroupConversationTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewConversationCell") as! NewConversationTableViewCell
        let friendList = self.friendList[indexPath.row]
        cell.populate(friendList)

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Bellow is the cell with the button and the action which will present the specific viewController which i want

```
class NewGroupConversationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func groupButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let messagesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupListViewController") as! GroupListViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(messagesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VoiceMe.GroupListViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb33171c4d0'

Comment: This is likely due to a mistake made when you were connecting the outlet/actions. Check them.

Comment: actually i double checked them and no clue..

Comment: Check your outlets and datasource / delegates are set up properly on your `GroupListViewController`. Is this a `UITableViewController`? The error isn't in your code from this VC but the one your pushing to.

Comment: Actually GroupListViewController is a UIViewController which include also a tableViewController

Comment: so, i made it worked after all , I had to include the delegate and datasource , so yea u were right

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it like this, so those are the steps to open you VC:

1 - Add a target function to your button in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewGroupConversationCell") as! NewGroupConversationTableViewCell
        cell.youButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleBtnAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.youButton.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    } 
    ...
```

2 - implement your selector:

```
func handleBtnAction(sender: UIButton){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let messagesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupListViewController") as! GroupListViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(messagesViewController, animated: true)
}
```